# How to store row numbers of the rows dropped through pd.dropna(df.dropna(axis=0))

Tags: python, pandas

Sample dataframe is given below

```
     c1    c2
0    1      2
1    nan    4
2    1      nan
3    4       1
4    nan    nan
```

After dropping using df.dropna(axis=0) function I wish to have a list of indexes of rows which were dropped as below.

```
 [1,2,4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.index[df.isnull().any(1)].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

Then,

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0)
```

Details:

1. df.isnull() returns a dataframe with True False for values
2. Next use the `any` method with axis=1 so it looks for any True on a
   row, this    will return a series with index as the index of the
   dataframe and    True for any row that as a True value.
3. Lastly, use booleaning index to filter out those indexes where the
   value in the series is not True.

Comment: df.index[df.isnull().any(1)].tolist()
 In this what does 1 inside any represent?

Comment: 1 is the axis so if any on that row, otherwise it would do any in a column.  Could be write out as `any(axis=1)`

Answer (score 5):

You can using `difference`

```
df.index.difference(df.dropna().index).tolist()
Out[420]: [1, 2, 4]
```

Or

```
df.index[df.isnull().any(1)].tolist()
Out[424]: [1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please add a bit of explanation on working of your code?

Comment: @VikasNS since it is quit easy , I will just adding here, 1st method is to find index different from the original df with the df after dropna, that is the index row you droped ; second is to find the null value firstly , and we using `any` check each row , if they contains one , we mark that row as True, then we using this blooean value to slice the original index to get the row we should drop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.where`. It'll return both the the rows and columns where your values are `NaN`.

```
np.where(df.isna())
(array([1, 2, 4, 4]), array([0, 1, 0, 1]))
```

Select the first item of the tuple, convert it to a set, and back to list:

```
list(set(np.where(df.isna())[0]))
[1, 2, 4]
```